Tableau and Azure Cosmos DB
I'm storing data in Azure CosmosDB. Those data are related to mathematical model output. Can I connect Tableau Bride to Azure CosmosDB to read the data and build dashboard according to the data?

could you please provide your approach

FYI this is off-topic: this is not a programming question, and you've provided nothing but a general set of requirements. Please read [ask].
